# Why doesn't the markdown file recognize the items "+"?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

I have a section in a Rmarkdown file such as:

````
* Building your YAML spec
    + we can get all the keys each kind supports
```{bash, eval=F}
#apiVersion: v1
#kind: Service
kubectl explain services --recursive
```
    + sepc section

```{bash, eval=F}
kubectl explain services.spec
```
    + sepc type

```{bash, eval=F}
kubectl explain services.spec.type
```
````

And after I rendered it:
[image]

My question is why it doesn't recognize the two pluses as items?

Answer (score 3):

Figure out the solution:  Use four spaces to indent code chunks between bullet points

````
* Building your YAML spec
    + we can get all the keys each kind supports
    ```{bash, eval=F}
      #apiVersion: v1
      #kind: Service
      kubectl explain services --recursive
    ```
    + sepc section

    ```{bash, eval=F}
      kubectl explain services.spec
    ```
    + sepc type

    ```{bash, eval=F}
      kubectl explain services.spec.type
    ```
````

This will output the expected items.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Rmarkdown` flavour of Markdown, the plus sign `+` is reserved for sub-items of a list. However, to be a sub-item, there needs to be an item. Unfortunately, when you insert a code chunk, you're ending the list, and therefore lose the connection between the original item "Building your YAML spec" and the following sub-items "sepc section" and "sepc type".

It may help to look at the rendered HTML. You should see that before the code chunk, there is a closing tag `</ul>`.

Comment: Thanks @M Turgeon. It makes sense. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: @DavidZ Off the top of my head, I don't see how this can be done in Markdown. There's probably a way to get exactly what you want in HTML, but of course it will be more verbose